# Modification of a JLabel

Tags: java, button, jlabel

I have a windows, which have the following private datas: a collections of vehicles and the current vehicle of the collection.

```
    package model;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;

import model.*;

/**
 *
 * @author jacques
 */
public class Windows extends JFrame
{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private Showroom sr;
        private Vehicle v;
        private JLabel txt;

        public Windows(Showroom sr)
        {
                super();
                this.sr=sr;
                this.v=sr.current();
                if(v.isSold())
                {    
                    this.txt= new JLabel("<html>Manufacturer: "+v.getManufacturer()+"<br/>"+
                        "Model: "+v.getModel()+"<br/>"+
                        "VIN: "+v.getVIN()+"<br/>"+
                        "Date of manufacture: "+v.getDatemanuf()+"<br/>"+
                        "Price: "+v.getPrice()+"<br/>"+
                        "Tax Band: "+v.getTaxband()+"<br/>"+
                        "Date of solding: "+v.getDatesold());
                }
                else
                {
                    this.txt= new JLabel("<html>Manufacturer: "+v.getManufacturer()+"<br/>"+
                        "Model: "+v.getModel()+"<br/>"+
                        "VIN: "+v.getVIN()+"<br/>"+
                        "Date of manufacture: "+v.getDatemanuf()+"<br/>"+
                        "Price: "+v.getPrice()+"<br/>"+
                        "Tax Band: "+v.getTaxband()+"<br/>");
                }
                build(sr);
        }

        public void build(Showroom sr)
        {
                setTitle("Vehicles"); //Titre de la fenêtre
                setSize(700,220); //Taille minimale fixée
                setLocationRelativeTo(null); //On centre la fenêtre sur l'écran
                setResizable(false); //On interdit la redimensionnement de la fenêtre
                setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //On dit à l'application de se fermer lors du clic sur la croix
                setContentPane(buildContentPane());
        }

        private JPanel buildContentPane()
        {
            JPanel panel=new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel panelbutton= new JPanel();
            JButton buttonprev= new JButton(new ButtonPrevious(this, "Previous vehicle"));
            JButton buttonnext= new JButton(new ButtonNext(this, "Next vehicle"));
            JButton buttonsell= new JButton("Sell");
            panelbutton.add(buttonprev);
            panelbutton.add(buttonnext);
            panelbutton.add(buttonsell);


            JPanel paneltext=new JPanel();          
            paneltext.add(txt);


            panel.add("North",panelbutton);
            panel.add("Center",paneltext);



            return panel;
        }

    public Showroom getSr()
    {
        return sr;
    }

    public Vehicle getV()
    {
        return v;
    }

    public JLabel getTxt()
    {
        return txt;
    }

    public void setV(Vehicle v)
    {
        this.v = v;
    }

    public void setTxt(JLabel txt)
    {
        this.txt = txt;
    }


}
```

The datas of the current vehicle are correctly displayed on the window.

But when i check the button next or previous, which normally change the current vehicle, the JLabel which displays the data of current vehicle dont change. Why ?

Here's the code of the abstract class which represent the action of one of the buttons.

```
    package model;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author jacques
 */
public class ButtonNext extends AbstractAction
{
    private Windows wdw;

        public ButtonNext(Windows wdw, String txt)
        {
                super(txt);
                this.wdw = wdw;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
                try
                {
                    wdw.setV(wdw.getSr().next());
                }
                catch(NoSuchElementException et)
                {

                }
                if(wdw.getV().isSold()==true)
                {
                    JLabel txt= new JLabel("<html>Manufacturer: "+wdw.getV().getManufacturer()+"<br/>"+
                        "Model: "+wdw.getV().getModel()+"<br/>"+
                        "VIN: "+wdw.getV().getVIN()+"<br/>"+
                        "Date of manufacture: "+wdw.getV().getDatemanuf()+"<br/>"+
                        "Price: "+wdw.getV().getPrice()+"<br/>"+
                        "Tax Band: "+wdw.getV().getTaxband()+"<br/>"+
                        "Date of solding: "+wdw.getV().getDatesold());
                    wdw.setTxt(txt);
                    wdw.repaint();
                    wdw.validate();
                }
                else
                {
                    JLabel txt= new JLabel("<html>Manufacturer: "+wdw.getV().getManufacturer()+"<br/>"+
                        "Model: "+wdw.getV().getModel()+"<br/>"+
                        "VIN: "+wdw.getV().getVIN()+"<br/>"+
                        "Date of manufacture: "+wdw.getV().getDatemanuf()+"<br/>"+
                        "Price: "+wdw.getV().getPrice()+"<br/>"+
                        "Tax Band: "+wdw.getV().getTaxband()+"<br/>");
                    wdw.setTxt(txt);
                    wdw.repaint();
                    wdw.validate();
                }
        }
}
```

Where is the problem ?

Thanks.

Comment: The relevant code must be in the question itself, not at pastebin.

Comment: I know, but it is more easier to paste in a pastebin than here.

Comment: Then ask pastebin users to answer your question. Or play by the rules and learn how to use Ctrl-V and Ctrl-K. Voting to close.

Comment: There is a string called txt and a jlabel called txt. But i agree with JB Nizet, post the relevant code here, it's really easy.

Comment: JBNizet -> I have done it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the text of the JLabel that is displayed in the frame, your actions *create* a new JLabel, and call `setTxt()` on the Windows object. That changes the field in the Windows object, but the label that is displayed is still the initial one.

Replace

```
JLabel txt= new JLabel("bla bla bla");
wdw.setTxt(txt);
wdw.repaint();
wdw.validate();
```

by

```
wdw.getTxt().setText("bla bla bla");
```

Also, avoid that like the plague:

```
catch(NoSuchElementException et)
{

}
```

It basically ignores an exception, hiding a bug. This should never happen. You shoulf check, before going to the next element, that there is one. Or even better, disable the next button when there is no next element.

And finally,

```
if(wdw.getV().isSold()==true)
```

should be written

```
if (wdw.getV().isSold())
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup, ça marche parfaitement (j'ai vu que tu étais un compatriote) ;)